# Unable to cd to iscsi mounted drive

Tags: permissions, mount, fstab

I am new to the Ubuntu environment. I have been a RH user for 20 years.

In a new install of 18.04 in VMWare 6.5U3 environment, the server will store security camera data.

I've attached Synology storage to VMware and the client server (the Ubuntu itself is on local storage).

When I mounted the video storage it showed up as `/dev/sb1`.  The local path is `/mnt/edvr/1`.  I am unable to `cd` into the `edvr` or `1` directory or even list them.  Permission on the `edvr` is set 700. I have been unable to mod it with the tools I usually use.

I am still getting used to the Ubuntu environment. I am used to logging in as root and acting like a god.  Ultimately my concern is if the permissions are not right in the child directories the system will not be able to delete the expired videos in 45 days.

This is my `fstab` entry

```
LABEL=/mnt/edvr/1 /mnt/edvr/1 ext4 errors=remount-ro      0 0
```

Comment: Probably this is an NTFS formatted drive. Please use the `-o umask=filePermissions,gid=ownerGroupID,uid=ownerID` options in `/etc/fstab`

Comment: definitely not NTFS. I formatted it from the command line.  It was un-allocated space in a 100TB storage system before I started.

Comment: If it is an ext. file system, you can always change the ownership and access permissions of a directory on it, using the commands `chown` and `chmod`.

Answer (score 0):

I have an internal disk mounted at /devsdb1 and it is mounted at `/media/graham/STORAGE`

[image]

I can `cd` to this volume in terminal as follows:

`cd media/graham/STORAGE`

[image]

I suggest you open `Disks` and view the mount point as shown and utilise that to navigate to your volume.

In order to access the drive, in terminal I used `sudo chown graham:graham /media/graham/STORAGE` and the drive is automatically mounted in fstab:

```
UUID=6f71cdf1-61c9-404c-9535-a917b6febf7b /media/graham/STORAGE ext4 defaults 0 0
```

I should think the same principle will apply to your mount.